# Sorting API data from Airtable

Tags: sorting, airtable

I'm trying to order the API responses from Airtable based on their `OrderNummer` instead of ID, since they are chronological and the ID is alphabetical.

This is the response I get:

```json
{
 "records": [
  {
   "id": "rec1IwAO4BzxvPmfl",
   "createdTime": "2023-11-15T17:06:19.000Z",
   "fields": {
    "TrackingURL": "https://tms.futuresupplychains.com/GUI/Tracking_New/Website/DocketTrack.aspx?st_Docnolist=GHSFGURJBK",
    "OrderNummer": "#1011",
    "Status": "fulfilled",
    "KlantNaam": "Harry van 't Kamp",
    "Bestemming": "'s-Hertogenbosch",
    "Bedrag": 14388,
    "TrackingNummer": "GHSFGURJBK",
    "DatumVanAankoop": "2023-11-15T17:05:52.000Z",
    "KlantMail": "test@test.com",
    "Update": "2023-11-15T17:06:09.000Z",
    "Adres": "Sweelinckplein 1 5216 EG, 's-Hertogenbosch, Netherlands"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "recHm3hyY1rGDib03",
   "createdTime": "2023-11-23T11:11:35.000Z",
   "fields": {
    "TrackingURL": "https://tms.futuresupplychains.com/GUI/Tracking_New/Website/DocketTrack.aspx?st_Docnolist=FKUGLUGLIJ",
    "OrderNummer": "#1025",
    "Status": "fulfilled",
    "KlantNaam": "Harry van 't Kamp",
    "Bestemming": "'s-Hertogenbosch",
    "Bedrag": 300,
    "TrackingNummer": "FKUGLUGLIJ",
    "DatumVanAankoop": "2023-11-23T12:11:32+01:00",
    "KlantMail": "test@test.com",
    "Update": "2023-11-23T12:11:47+01:00",
    "Adres": "Sweelinckplein 1, 5216 EG, 's-Hertogenbosch, Netherlands"
   }
  },
```

I tried using a `?sort_by=ordernummer&order=asc` or similar functions, but they gave the same output as given above. Other ways to make it work in chronological order are good as well, such as ordering by `DatumVanAankoop` or `createdTime` for instance.